# Global exception/error handling in asp.net mvc core and dapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dapper

I am using Asp.net core and Dapper in our App.Here is my User Repository Add method.(connection string will be injected through dependency)

```
public User Add(User user)
        {
            string query = @"Insert into Users(UserName,Email,LastName,Password) values (@UserName , @Email, @LastName , @Password );
            select Cast(Scope_Identity() as int)";

            Try
            {
             using (var db = connectionFactory.GetOpenConnection())
             {
                  int id = db.Query<int>(query, user).Single();
                  user.UserId = id;
                  return user;
             }

        } Catch(Exception e){  //log exception}

        }
```

And in my startup class i have included global exception handler

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
             loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // StatusCode pages to gracefully handle status codes 400-599.
                app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("~/Home/StatusCodePage");

                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

        }
```

My Quetion is whether try catch is requered in each method of repository? Or asp.net core  will automatically handles the global exception/ Sql excption?

Please let me know correct method becuase i dont want to include try catch in each method

Comment: the term you refer to is **cross-cutting concern**. read up on that topic in relation to global error handling. ideally you want to keep your implementations lean and having single responsibilities (SRP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A try catch is the best way to be safe but in a perfect world best practice would be to write unit tests around those situations. I came across this with my last stand alone project at work. A well written unit test will tell you the exact issue with your code. I love them. :)

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Can you elaborate it with an example? It will be very easy to understand.

Comment: Well it's a large subject, first I must ask, have you created unit tests before?

Comment: @MistaGoustan i am new to asp.net core..i am not did units test before..if u provide example code...it will help us

Comment: Okay, if you've never done this it's quite a broad subject to cover, but is most definitely worth looking to. Your code will become much more stable and reliable. you want to know about TDD (Test Driven Development) as well, as they go very very well together.  but on this subject the best way you will learn honestly is not reading up that much but by just doing it. 

Unit Testing:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh694602.aspx

TDD:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212233.aspx